# java how does readObject in objectinputstream knows how many bytes to read?

Tags: java, python, sockets, java-io

In socket I/O, may I know how does a `objectinputstream` `readObject` knows how many bytes to read? Is the content length encapsulated inside the bytes itself or does it simply reads all the available bytes in the buffer itself?

I am asking this because I was referring to the Python socket how-to and it says

> Now if you think about that a bit, you’ll come to realize a
>   fundamental truth of sockets: messages must either be fixed length
>   (yuck), or be delimited (shrug), or indicate how long they are (much
>   better), or end by shutting down the connection. The choice is
>   entirely yours, (but some ways are righter than others).

However in another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501378/java-serialization-objectinputstream-readobject-check-if-will-block), @DavidCrawshaw mentioned that `

> So readObject() does not know how much data it will read, so it does
>   not know how many objects are available.

I am interested to know how it works...

Answer (score 2):

You're over-interpreting the answer you cited. `readObject()` doesn't know how many bytes it *will* read, ahead of time, but once it starts reading it is just parsing an input stream according to a protocol, that consists of tags, primitive values, and objects, which in turn consist of tags, primitive values, and other objects. It doesn't have to know ahead of time. Consider the similar-ish case of XML. You don't know how long the document will be ahead of time, or each element, but you know when you've read it all, because the protocol tells you.

Comment: so does it means that the content length is inside the stream's message? What if the number of available bytes in the stream is lesser than what is stated? does it blocks until more is available or simply throws a StreamCorruptedException?

Comment: @goh it means that the content length is NOT inside the stream's message, and it doesn't need to me.  When you are reading a book, do you need to know how many words are in the book, or can you read one word at a time until you get to the finish? All `Stream` block when you read but there is not enough data. If the Stream has ended you will get an EOFException. Only non-blocking NIO doesn't blocking which is why its is hard to use Object Streams with non-blocking NIO.

Comment: @goh "What if the number of available bytes in the stream is lesser than what is stated": it blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The `readOject()` method is using BlockedInputStream to read the byte.If you check the `readObject` of `ObjectInputStream` , it is calling

```
readObject0(false).

private Object readObject0(boolean unshared) throws IOException {
    boolean oldMode = bin.getBlockDataMode();
    if (oldMode) {
        int remain = bin.currentBlockRemaining();
        if (remain > 0) {
        throw new OptionalDataException(remain);
        } else if (defaultDataEnd) {
        /*
         * Fix for 4360508: stream is currently at the end of a field
         * value block written via default serialization; since there
         * is no terminating TC_ENDBLOCKDATA tag, simulate
         * end-of-custom-data behavior explicitly.
         */
        throw new OptionalDataException(true);
        }
        bin.setBlockDataMode(false);
    }

    byte tc;
    while ((tc = bin.peekByte()) == TC_RESET) {
        bin.readByte();
        handleReset();
    }
```

which is reading from the stream is using `bin.readByte().`bin is `BlockiedDataInputStream` which in turns use `PeekInputStream` to read it.This class finally is using InputStream.read().
From the description of the read method:

```
/**
     * Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
     * returned as an <code>int</code> in the range <code>0</code> to
     * <code>255</code>. If no byte is available because the end of the stream
     * has been reached, the value <code>-1</code> is returned. This method
     * blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected,
     * or an exception is thrown.
```

So basically it reads byte after byte until it encounters -1.So As EJP mentioned, it never know ahead of time how many bytes are there to be read. Hope this will help you in understanfing it.

Comment: in the case of sockets, the end of stream is never reached unless the socket is closed. How would it knows when to unblock then?

Comment: What do you mean by end of stream is never reached.However, the mechanism and concept is same whether you read from socket or file.All of it knows, there is an inputstream to read the data from.So by default when Java reads a byte from this stream using IO (not NIO) , it is a blocking operation.See more about this from java E 6 doc.

Comment: @goh It unblocks when (a) data is available, (b) end of stream is reached, or (c) an error occurs. This is clearly stated in the documentation.