# Java chat application using Swing (Conceptual)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I want to write a chat application in Java using Swing as an interface.

I have come up with an idea (with the help of [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer)), but I am not sure whether it is the best way to go about this.

There are two `Blockinqueue` queues in the `main` Thread, one for incoming messages and one for outgoing messages.

There are four threads, two for outgoing and two for incoming messages, one each to handle the GUI and the socket.

**Threads for outgoing messages:**

1. `ActionListener (Swing)`: Is triggered when user clicks "send" in GUI. The thread adds the new message to the Outgoing Queue and triggers `notifyAll()` on it.
2. `socketOutgoing`: Has access to socket. Sleeps, with `wait()` on Outgoing Queue, until it is notified. Sends new messages in Outgoing Queue through socket, then goes back to sleep again.

**Threads for incoming messages:**

1. `socketIncoming:` Has access to socket. Checks continuously for new
   message in socket (how?). When there is a new message, adds it to
   the Outgoing Queue and triggers `notifyAll()` on it.
2. `Swingworker displayIncoming`: Sleeps, with `wait()` on Incoming Queue, until it is notified. Displays new messages in GUI, then goes back to sleep again.

While this would theoretically work, it seems a bit messy (and unreliable) to have four threads for this.

Is there a more practical solution?

**Note to future readers:** My description of `socketIncoming` was misguided: It is not possible to "check continuously for new message in socket".

When you call `ObjectInputStream#readObject()`, and there is no new message, it simply waits, or "blocks", until a new messages arrives. There is no way to check beforehand whether a new message has arrived. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1501378/805556).

Comment: *"Checks continuously for new message in socket (how?)"* Basically `while(true) { checkForMessage(); }` but you don't want it to run completely unhinged. You might look at [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and its older counterpart [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for scheduling a single task at a certain rate. *"it seems a bit messy (and unreliable) to have four threads for this"* Multiple threads keep complex tasks off the EDT and the GUI responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was thinking about doing something like I would probably set up two queues, an outgoing and incoming queue.  These would be used to "stage" messages.

The idea being that outgoing messages would be placed into the outgoing queue and when `Thread` was able to, it would pop off the next message and send it.  When the queue was empty, it would simply "wait" until a new message become available.

The concept would work in reverse for the incoming queue.  The `Thread` would read a message and push it onto the incoming queue.

Some other process (possibly a `SwingWorker`) would be monitoring the queue and pop the next message of it and re-sync it with the GUI.

You might find [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) of some use.

How the underlying protocol actually worked would dictate a lot more of the details though

Comment: I've added a lot of details. Could you please take a look and tell me what you think?

Comment: You might want to do a search on blocking queues, as these might actually be capable of reducing some of the workload.  Additional, this all depends on how your protocol is written.  Sending a message should have some kind of receipt to it, letting the sender now if the message was received okay, was delivered or was rejected for some reason, for example.  This complicates the problem, as you can't simply "read" for the next message from the incoming stream in another thread, as it might get the "protocol" messages for example...

Comment: Thanks so much. About blocking queues: I can simply use those instead of the `ArrayLists` I had planned, right?

Comment: If I understand your concern correctly, I might not be able to distinguish between user messages and protocol messages? Mine is a rather simplistic implementation, so I am not sure that I will even add "message received" notifictations, but since I am not sending messages in plaintext anyway, but serializing them along with their metadata, I think that's not an issue.

Comment: Pretty much.  The intention is, if you can find an implementation to do so, they should block when you call `get` until something is available

Comment: (protocol issues) So long as you've thought about and are aware of it ;)

Comment: One more question: You said, "If you can find an implementation..." Isn't the native BlockingQueue implementation enough?

Comment: Yeah, it should be...but you'll need to read the documentation carefully as most state for the `poll` method something like *"or returns `null` if this queue is empty"*

Comment: @MadProgrammer To make scalable chat server, using only two thread with blocking queue it will generate huge latency when number of client increases

Answer (score 1):

for a simple chat application you shall have two parts

1. Client part
2. Server part.

Now, you have to decide which protocol you want to use for your communication [Tcp] or [Udp]. Though your message transmission should be reliable so you have to use java Tcp ServerSocket. your server will be multi-threaded means for each client connect with server will have separate thread to handle all message communication from that client.

For Client side, it will have GUI componenet and one dedicated thread to receive message from server. when you want to send message to any user, just pass the message and send through client socket.

Comment: Thanks, I've already decided on TCP and am currently coding the client.

Comment: I've edited my answer, could you please take a look?