# Java ObjectInputStream: How to check for new data?

Tags: java, io, objectinputstream

I am using Java and `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to write a TCP client/server pair. The server sends data through the `ObjectOutputStream`, and the client receives the data in the `ObjectInputStream`.

Part of the client code is below:

```
try {
    newMessage = (Message) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(newMessage);

} catch (Exception e) { // temporary
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Unfortunately [`readObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) is a blocking method, which means that if there is no new Object in the `ObjectInputStream`, it will simply wait until one arrives.

(Note: Unlike [`readInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readInt%28%29), `readObject()` does not throw an `EOFException` when the EOF has been reached.)

This is a problem: This may be in a separate thread, but I do not want the thread to hang while waiting for a new message to arrive. I would rather use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule a periodic check of `ObjectInputStream`.

How can I check whether there is new data in the `ObjectInputStream`, so that I can avoid  calling `readObject()` when there is no new data?

Comment: Yes, most read/write operations are blocking but I do believe some people create a new `Thread` per client connection.

Comment: I should've clarified: This is in a separate thread. But I would rather have more control over `readObject()`.

Comment: What is the problem with a dedicated thread that blocks?  IMHO a lot cleaner than polling.  Also please remeber that the object being written needs to implement serializable.

Comment: @user2310289: Now that you ask, I cannot name a specific reason—It just didn't make sense to me to have a thread stop until one of its methods finishes.
Yep, I know the serializable part.

Comment: You are mistaken about EOFException. readObject() most certainly does throw it at end of stream, precisely like readInt() and friends.

Comment: Are you sure? Do compare the documentation of [`readInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) and [`readObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29). `ReadObject`'s makes no mention of `EOFExceptions`.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler What do you mean by more control over `readObject()`? The idea is you have a `Connection` class with the I/O streams and then have some sort of `ConnectionListener` which will fire particular events, such as receiving data and on connection closed.

Comment: @EJP: I'm not very experienced with Exceptions, but doesn't the code above check for an `EOFException`? When I run it, the thread hangs on the `readObject()` line. Is it not reasonable to suppose that rather than throw an `EOFException`, the method waits if it detects an EOF?

Comment: @JoshM: I have something like this set up. A blocking method didn't make any sense intuitively, that's why I wanted to change it.

Comment: I repeat. The readObject() method throws EOFException at end of stream. I can't make head or tail of the part starting 'is it not reasonable to suppose'. It seems you may be confused about what 'end of stream' means. It means the peer has closed the connection, not just 'no more data for the moment'.

Comment: By "is it not reasonable..." I meant "Would it not be internally coherent..."
Sorry, I wasn't aware of this definition of end of stream. Why isn't the exception in the docs? I find that strange.

Comment: It wouldn't be internally coherent to block when the peer has disconnected. There will never be any more data so there is nothing to block for. There is no other definition of end of stream.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not think of that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct implementation is to block. Attempts to try to figure out if there is enough data available will not work reliably since you don't even know how many bytes you have to look for. Streams also often don't know how much data is available because that depends on the somewhere in your operating system handled network stack and other parameters.

There is a nonblocking alternative to blocking streams in the `java.nio` package which can handle multiple connections in a single thread but that's an entirely different story.

Comment: Thanks. Given your answer, user2310289's comment, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1501425/805556) from a near-duplicate question, I believe that blocking is the best way to go.

Comment: It is how streams are designed and polling (i.e. periodically checking) consumes just pointless CPU time while a blocked thread consumes none. If you want to run code once something happens, you would notify / trigger an event.

Answer (score 0):

Writing side can write object into byte array via ByteArrayOutputStream. Then it sends length (int) and then byte arrray. Receving sides reads the length and then bytes into byte array, then reads object from byte array via ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: Thanks, but I'll keep the blocking method instead.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using a NIO framework such as Netty to solve this problem. Netty is event based. When an incoming message is decoded by the NIO-thread(which is managed by Netty itself), you will receive a corresponding event. Then you can just send the message to your own working thread and process it.

Or if you don't like to involve 3rd-party dependencies, just use two thread to solve this problem. One thread loops and blocks on `readObject()`, once it gets an incoming message, it puts the message to a Queue such as `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`. And the other thread is scheduled to check the queue with some rate, with `LinkedBlockingQueue.peek()` method. If `peek` returns something, just `poll` it out from the queue and handle it. If not, the thread won't be blocked and so it can to something else.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a bit complicated—I'll stick with the blocking method.